# export and import schema using expdp and impdp

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I use [this tuotrial](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g) to export/import schema. The steps in the tutorial are working until the expdp command, see the screenshot:
[image]

I am using oracle12c. Any Idea?

Comment: have you granted read write permission on the directory to the user who is exporting?

Comment: And the operating system directory that the Oracle directory object points do exists on the database server, and is read/writable by the Oracle operating system account? (Creating an Oracle directory does not automatically create the O/S directory; I've seen people trip over that before)

Comment: @AlexPoole well I have created it with CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dpdir AS 'C:\oracledata\dir';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dpdir TO scott;. Its confirmed that this directory have been created but  the directory is not created in the file system. Should it be existing in the file system before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [article you linked to](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g#GettingStarted) notes that:

> The directory object is only a pointer to a physical directory, creating it does not actually create the physical directory on the file system of the database server.

You have to create the physical operating system directory separately, outside the database. That physical directory has to be readable and writable by the operating system user that is running the Oracle database; as you seem to be on Windows that will be the account the services are running under.

You can create the physical directory before or after creating the directory object as they are completely independent, except when Oracle is trying to access it through a UTL_FILE or related activity - data pump uses UTL_FILE, as you can see from the error message stack.

The `CREATE DIRECTORY` doesn't check that the physical directory it points to exists; and you can delete or create the physical directory without Oracle noticing; as long as it is there are accessible when you try to use it.

From [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5008.htm):

> A directory object specifies an alias for a directory on the server file system ...

and

> For file storage, you must also create a corresponding operating system directory, an Oracle Automatic Storage Management (Oracle ASM) disk group, or a directory within an Oracle ASM disk group. Your system or database administrator must ensure that the operating system directory has the correct read and write permissions for Oracle Database processes.
>
> Privileges granted for the directory are created independently of the permissions defined for the operating system directory, and the two may or may not correspond exactly. For example, an error occurs if sample user hr is granted READ privilege on the directory object but the corresponding operating system directory does not have READ permission defined for Oracle Database processes.